# how/where can I 'clear' the checkouts on a sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Trying to update a sharepoint list with a powershell script but I am getting several errors like this:

```
Error Occurred (04/28/2018 19:13:38) with error message: Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "The file "mysite.aspx" is
checked out for editing by bla\thisuser1
Error Occurred (04/28/2018 19:13:38) with error message: Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "The file "mysite.aspx" is
checked out for editing by bla\thisuser2
Error Occurred (04/28/2018 19:13:38) with error message: Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "The file "mysite.aspx" is
checked out for editing by bla\thisuser3
```

etc

This is a part of the powershell script once it hits the update() statement it throws the error above:

```
if ($li["Topics"] -eq $null)
{
        $li["Topics"] = $si.NewTopic
        $li.Update()
}
```

Question: how/where can I 'clear' the checkouts on this sharepoint list? I could not find a method like UndoCheckout on the $li listitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SPFile.UndoCheckOut` method

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.undocheckout.aspx

Based on the list type you have, either of these two should work.

```
$item.UndoCheckOut()
//or
$item.File.UndoCheckOut()
```

Also make sure run this command on files checked out. if file is not checked out command gives error.

```
if ($item.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") {
    $item.File.UndoCheckOut()
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a method that works directly on the listitem?

Comment: @bierhier I edited my answer how it helps. Also what is the type of the list? Clearly it's not a Custom List because custom lists do not have check in/out. Only Pages, document libraries have this feature.

Comment: I think it is a document library